I'm trying to create a spinner but my code is not working
I'm trying to create a spinner which spins during network call but it is not working. I tried to use classList add method to add/remove hidden class in which display :hidden property is set.
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Meme Generator</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/TrollFace.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Meme Generator</h1>
        </header>
        <main>
            <button class="button-5" id="generateMemeBtn" role="button">Generate Meme</button>
            <div id="memeContainer">
                <div id="loadingSpinner" class="spinner hidden"></div>
                <h1>Hello there !!</h1>
                <img src="./hi-hello.gif" alt="">
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

CSS
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#f8f9fa;
    padding: 40px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    height:75%;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

header {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: #212529;
}

.button-5 {
    margin: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #d00000;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02) 0 1px 3px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-flex;
    font-family: system-ui,-apple-system,system-ui,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    justify-content: center;
    line-height: 1.25;
    min-height: 3rem;
    padding: calc(.875rem - 1px) calc(1.5rem - 1px);
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 250ms;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    width: auto;
  }
  
  .button-5:hover {
    background-color: #d00000;
    box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 4px 12px;
  }
  
  .button-5:hover {
    transform: translateY(-1px);
  }
  
  .button-5:active {
    background-color: #9c0404;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .06) 0 2px 4px;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

#memeContainer {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 200px;
    height: 60vh;
    width: 38vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #212529;

}

#memeContainer img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 90%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.spinner {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border: 5px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom-color: #FF3D00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: rotation 1s linear infinite;
   
}

.hidden{
    display: none;
}


@keyframes rotation {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    } 


JS
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const generateMemeBtn = document.getElementById('generateMemeBtn');
    const memeContainer = document.getElementById('memeContainer');
    const loadingSpinner = document.getElementById('loadingSpinner');

    generateMemeBtn.addEventListener('click', memeApi);

    function memeApi()
   {

    loadingSpinner.classList.remove('hidden');
    console.log(loadingSpinner.className)
    memeContainer.innerHTML = '';

    const url = 'https://meme-api.com/gimme/15';

    fetch(url)
        .then(data => data.json() )
        .then(data => {
            const memes = data;
            const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * memes.count);
            const meme = memes.memes[randomIndex];
            


            loadingSpinner.classList.add('hidden');
            memeContainer.innerHTML = `
                <h2>${meme.title}</h2>
                <img src="${meme.url}" alt="${meme.author}">
            `;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching meme:', error);
            loadingSpinner.classList.add('hidden');
            memeContainer.innerHTML = '<p>Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.</p>';
        });


   } 
});


I'm expecting a slider which rotate during the API fetching and then it disappears. When it got the result.

Please read carefully : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask , and specialy : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ==> Remove all code that is unrelated to your question and create a minimal, reproducible example that can highlight only the part related to the topic of your question.

All you need to do is move your spinner div outside of your container div, so that the spinner doesn't get replaced by the meme when it is loaded.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const generateMemeBtn = document.getElementById('generateMemeBtn');
    const memeContainer = document.getElementById('memeContainer');
    const loadingSpinner = document.getElementById('loadingSpinner');

    generateMemeBtn.addEventListener('click', memeApi);

    function memeApi()
   {

    loadingSpinner.classList.remove('hidden');
    console.log(loadingSpinner.className)
    memeContainer.innerHTML = '';

    const url = 'https://meme-api.com/gimme/15';

    fetch(url)
        .then(data => data.json() )
        .then(data => {
            const memes = data;
            const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * memes.count);
            const meme = memes.memes[randomIndex];
            


            loadingSpinner.classList.add('hidden');
            memeContainer.innerHTML = `
                <h2>${meme.title}</h2>
                <img src="${meme.url}" alt="${meme.author}">
            `;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching meme:', error);
            loadingSpinner.classList.add('hidden');
            memeContainer.innerHTML = '<p>Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.</p>';
        });


   } 
});
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#f8f9fa;
    padding: 40px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    height:75%;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

header {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: #212529;
}

.button-5 {
    margin: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #d00000;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02) 0 1px 3px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-flex;
    font-family: system-ui,-apple-system,system-ui,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    justify-content: center;
    line-height: 1.25;
    min-height: 3rem;
    padding: calc(.875rem - 1px) calc(1.5rem - 1px);
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 250ms;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    width: auto;
  }
  
  .button-5:hover {
    background-color: #d00000;
    box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 4px 12px;
  }
  
  .button-5:hover {
    transform: translateY(-1px);
  }
  
  .button-5:active {
    background-color: #9c0404;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .06) 0 2px 4px;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

#memeContainer {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 200px;
    height: 60vh;
    width: 38vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #212529;

}

#memeContainer img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 90%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.spinner {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border: 5px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom-color: #FF3D00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: rotation 1s linear infinite;
   
}

.hidden{
    display: none;
}


@keyframes rotation {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
} 
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Meme Generator</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <button class="button-5" id="generateMemeBtn" role="button">Generate Meme</button>
      <div id="memeContainer">
        <h1>Hello there !!</h1>
        <img src="./hi-hello.gif" alt="">
      </div>
      <!-- Move your spinner out of the "memeContainer", so it doesn't get replaced by the meme -->
      <div id="loadingSpinner" class="spinner hidden"></div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>



